# What is the best practice for refining located anchors?

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

I've been working on some example tests using the Unity samples/SDK and was curious about whether there is an existing process for refining anchor poses over time, specifically, after locating anchors through a NearLocationCriteria. Connected anchors are noticeably offset after locating which isn't really that surprising as they're quite a ways away. Is there a specific way to refine a cloud anchor's pose as we approach it (same idea as the wayfinding green arrow example app from the initial presentation https://youtu.be/CVmfP8TaqNU?t=2859) or is the correct way to just attempt to locate it again at an interval? Love the sdk and everything it's building towards.

Thanks in advance.